# Why this regex could detect "testing" and "telephone" when "l" is explicit?

Tags: regex

The regex is `[^\r\n.!]*(?i)tel*[^\r\n]+` but it somehow could detect the words `telephone` and `testing`.

But why `testing`? I don't get this because the `l` is explicitly written in the regex.

https://regex101.com/r/7Z8KkK/1

At Regex101, it explains...

```
te matches the characters te literally (case insensitive)
l matches the character l with index 10810 (6C16 or 1548) literally (case insensitive)
```

But I don't understand the explanation and why it views `te` and `l` separately.

Comment: Well `l*` means the letter `l` zero or more times.  Perhaps you intended to use: `[^\r\n.!]*(?i)tel.*[^\r\n]+` ?

Comment: That should be an answer @TimBiegeleisen and you beat me to it :D

Comment: The `*` after the `l` says you can have the letter l 0, 1 or many times. 
testing is l 0 times. if you the entire string "tel" to be affected by the *, put it between (): (tel)*

Comment: To add to it it will match any word that has "te" on it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My intention is to read "tel" not "tel." but I followed what Pabluez said by using "(tel)" but it doesn't work. Testing still gets matched.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Should I just remove the * meaning "tel" instead of "tel*" to detect "tel" literally?

Comment: `tel` matches `t`, `e`, `l`. `tel*` matches `t`, `e` and any number of `l`. `(tel)*` matches any number of repetitions of the sequence `t`, `e`, `l` (it matches the string containing `testing` because there are 0 repetitions of `tel`). `(tel)+` matches any _positive_ number of repetitions of this sequence (so it would not match `testing`). And `tel.*` matches `t`, `e`, `l`, and any number of repetitions of any character (not just `.`).